# "Value is declared but never read" but i am declaring the value

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to build a portfolio website in React ,i'm very new to React (about 3 days), and i have imported some code for the website nav bar and declared it in the code but it doesn't show up on the website and vscode says that the value was not declared. How do i fix this?

I've tried turning the code into a component and rearranging the code but i still get the same result.

---

App.js - main code

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import navBar from './navBar/navBar';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="app">
      //navBar that won't show up
      <navBar />
      <div className="landingPage"></div>
      <div className="projectPage"></div>
      <div className="aboutPage"></div>
      <div className="footer"></div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default App;
```

---

Code for the navBar

```
import React from "react";
import "./navBar.css";

function navBar() {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>NAVBAR PLACEHOLDER</h1>
        </div>
    )
}

export default navBar;
```

Comment: Are you sure **./navBar/navBar.js** is the correct path?

Comment: react components should use a first letter capitalized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question title is little bit wierd. You have fixed the value error in your code. But you still have error with the component:

```
//navBar that won't show up
<navBar />
```

In react custom built components name should always start with capital letter. So do this:

```
import NavBar from './navBar/navBar';
// --  ^^ you can name it anything as it's default import

<NavBar />
```

Comment: Should? Or must?

Comment: Since there's the word always, it doesn't matter, I think. And BTW, we can also use lowerCase component if we wish :) `{navBar()}`. Capitalization is only required for HTML markup.

Comment: "it doesn't matter" - the words "should" and "must", in tech specs, are very specific and different. "should" is advisory only, with or without "always"